# How to remove some comments from a node?

Tags: 7, comments, nodes

I created a new table in the database to associate comments to the node version they were submitted against. Now when the node renders, I only want to display comments that are associated with the specific node vid. I thought about querying the db in hook_node_view to remove the comments that don't apply, but ideally only comments associated with the vid are added to the node in the first place. Is there a better way to implement this? Can I get at the node right before the comments are added to it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the comment metadata populated after node_load comes from [comment_node_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_node_load/7). But indeed the comments themselves aren't added until view time at [comment_node_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_node_view/7), which calls [comment_node_page_additions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_node_page_additions/7) which adds the renderable comments, which calls [comment_get_thread()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_get_thread/7) to load the cids.

So perhaps it would take adding vid column to the comment table, and then adding vid condition in comment_get_thread...hmmm.